# React + Firebase Empty Array

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, reactfire

I'm trying to render my items in my Firebase database (of which I have 3) to my React component's page and am having a little difficulty.

```
var config = {
  // ...
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: []
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref("items");
    this.bindAsArray(ref, "items");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.state.items.map(function (item, i) {
          return (
            <h1 className="white">Item</h1>
          )
        }) }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

reactMixin(App.prototype, ReactFireMixin);

export default App;
```

Am I doing this correctly, shouldn't I be seeing three repeated `<h1>` elements?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

JSbin example: http://jsbin.com/xodobohexi/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Are you seeing any console errors? How is your `App` component being used?

Comment: If there are 3 items, your code should indeed be rendering 3 elements. Can you set up a reproduction of the problem in a jsfiddle/jsbin, so we can have a look at it?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Updated original question with JSBin example.

Comment: Your JSBin doesn't work since `render` needs an enclosing `<div>`. That will fix the `Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag` error in the console. But fixing that just leads to a `TypeError: this.bindAsArray is not a function` error since your example doesn't even use ReactFire.

You need to use ReactFire as a mixin, not as an ES6 class or HOC. Docs for using ReactFire are here: https://github.com/firebase/reactfire/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md

I'm hoping to update it to work with ES6 classes soon: https://github.com/firebase/reactfire/issues/38

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use ReactFire, you need to begin using it as a mixin, as already explained by @jacobawenger. If you'd like to render it without ReactFire, you could do the following:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      items: []
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref("items");
    ref.once('value').then(snap=>{
      if(snap.val()!==null){
        let items=Object.keys(snap.val()).map(item=> return snap.val([item])
        this.setState({items})
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    const {items} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {items.map((item, i) => { return <h1 key={i}>{item}</h1> }) }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```